# Is it a good practice to leave space before mathematical text?

Tags: syntax, mathematics

I used to write equations in the following way:

```
Text 
%Empty line
\[
 code  
\]  
%Empty line
 Text
```

I have noticed that with this syntax there is more space above the maths than beneath them. Is that a bad practice or contrary to the "rules" of TeX?

Comment: Bad practice. After 20 years of latex editing I can usually spot then in the output. Not that one liner construction like this has a build it space saving feature if the eqn and the text before is short. That does not kick in if there is a blank line above.

Comment: It is always wrong to have a blank line (but of course it is OK to have a comment as you show that has no effect at all)

Comment: Additionally, since a blank line starts a new paragraph, it is also semantically wrong as one never starts a paragraph with displayed math

Comment: if you mean that your document really has a blank line and not a comment I suggest you edit the example shown. The blank line above is wrong a blank line below is right or wrong depending whether you intend a new paragraph to start after the equation.

Comment: How can we retain readability though? I mean imagine that we write `equation`, `align` environments one after the other. Personally, the whitespace makes the code more clear to me. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely bad practice and you've already noticed that, didn't you?

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-6]
\[
a+b=c
\]
\lipsum[2][1-6]

\lipsum*[1][1-6]

\[
a+b=c
\]

\lipsum[2][1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the first case, TeX uses `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` above and below the equation and you get a symmetric spacing.

In the second case, there is an empty line above the equation, followed by `\abovedisplayshortskip` and the equation is followed by `\belowdisplayshortskip`, making the spacing *very* asymmetric.

The empty line after the equation is not bad practice *per se*, but you only use it when the text after the equation starts a new paragraph. Which can happen or not, depending on the full text.